# How to play mp3 file from my Box.com account in JPlayer?

Tags: c#, box-api, jplayer

I have done Box.com Authentication in my c# application.

Accessing the list of mp3 files from my Box.com account is also achieved.

What I need is to play a mp3 file from my Box.com account.

I need the URI of my Mp3 file from Box.com account to pass to JPlayer.

Box.com provides URI as "https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_XXXXXXX" which is not working in Jplayer as I already tried this.

Any alternative for this?